# How to validate the beginning of an IP in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate and IP that start with 20.4.xxx.xxx and writing this regular expression that is not working. any ideas on how to do it. I'm really new on regular expressions.

```
 if (ip =~" /([10]|[5]\d|1?\d\d?)/g")
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't use `=~`, that's Perl.

Comment: If you want to match `20`, why does your regexp start with `[10]`, which matches either `1` or `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex solution is not best choice for this:

```js
let r = /^20\.4\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/;

let tests = [
  '20.4.0.1',
  '20.4.12.255',

  '20.4.256.255',
  '20.4.0.256',
  '120.4.0.1',
  '20.04.0.1',
  '200.4.0.1',
];

console.log(tests.map(ip => r.test(ip)))
```

You can test it manually more efficient/supportable way:

```js
function test(ip) { 
  let parts = ip.split('.').map(part => parseInt(part, 10));
  if (parts.length !== 4) return false;
  if (parts.shift() !== 20) return false;
  if (parts.shift() !== 4) return false;
  return parts.every(part => part >= 0 && part <= 255);  
}

let tests = [
  '20.4.0.1',
  '20.4.12.255',
  '20.04.0.1', // it's true while regexp above has false negative here

  '20.4.256.255',
  '20.4.0.256',
  '120.4.0.1',
  '200.4.0.1',
];

console.log(tests.map(test))
```

Comment: im trying to use your response but I keep getting an error that maps is not a function...I trying to validate one Ip not an array. Do you think that the reason?

Comment: Do snippets in the answer work as expected? First provides a regexp, second test function with `test(ip)` interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help bro, I'm using your second option

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(/^20\.4\./.test(ip)){
 <your code if true here>
}
```

the regex is:

^  = beginning of string
\.= matches a dot (only a dot would match any character, therefore escape it

the **.test()** method returns true if it is a match

Comment: This tests the start of the string which would also match for example 20.4.2018

Answer (score 1):

Split your string, and test the first two array elements.

```
const octets = ip.split('.');

if(octets[0] === "20" && octets[1] === "4"){
    //success
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, easy way to validate the beginning of the ip